# .Net 4.0 dlls in a SharePoint 2010 Project

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How can I create and use a SharePoint 2010 project that references a .Net 4.0 class library project? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 uses .NET 3.5 SP1