# Use Asp.Net UserControl as a SharePoint WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-2010, user-controls, web-parts

I have a bit of an awkward scenario (I think). I have a Asp.Net UserControl in a project which targets the 4.0 framework and also uses a 3rd party dll (Telerik controls).

I tried using vs2010 to copy the usercontrol and required references to the Visual Webpart within an Empty Sharepoint (2010) project. But it will not allow the references to dlls which in turn, reference the 4.0 framework etc.

So my question... is it possible to do this? If so, the steps in a bit of detail would be VERY appreciated.

thanks,

KS

Comment: SharePoint 2010 works with ASP.NET 3.5 and won't work with ASP.NET 4.0, hence you can't just copy usercontrols into a visual wepart. Even though WebParts inherit from UserControls they are not the same, because of SharePoint specific stuff in there.

Comment: I just created a sample project which targets the 4.0 framework and installed it on a Sharepoint 2010 site using SmartPart2010 (Codeplex). Seems to work just fine so I guess the issue with more complex projects is making sure all the dependencies are signed and installed. I didn't even need to create a Sharepoint Project - it's great - although let's see if I can get my target UserControl project up and running.

Comment: Interesting. Though still it is not MS recommended to use ASP.NET 4.0 and I doubt you will be able to build real solutions with it. A standard Class library project and building a SmartPart and deploying it to the usercontrols folder - sure that works, but it ain't the SP way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your third party dll is for .net 3.5 then you can use the dll and use the user control in a same way the smartPart project loads or you can just use the smartpart web part.

But **you can not use .net version 4 assembly in sharepoint 2010**. SP2010 is targeted for .net 3.5 and only can use assemblies with version 3.5 and before.

The reason you could test the smartpart environment is most probably because you didn't import any dll's targeted for .net 4 or none of the methods included in the uc were from .net 3.5.

Sharepoint 2010 .net version so question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031873/net-4-0-dlls-in-a-sharepoint-2010-project).